# pcap_open_live unable to open eth0 hexinject

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, virtualbox

I am currently working with hexinject( sniffer and injector), and after making its object file using gcc, when I am trying to run it, it shows that it is unable to open the adapter.

Here is the code portion of the source file which calls pcap_open_live function;

```
/* Parse cmdline options */
parseopt(argc, argv);

/* Open the output device */
if ( (fp = pcap_open_live( options.device, // name of the device
                           BUFSIZ,         // portion of the packet to capture
                           1,              // promiscuous mode
                           -1,             // read timeout
                           errbuf          // error buffer
                          )) == NULL)

{
    fprintf(stderr,"\nUnable to open the adapter. %s is not supported.\n", options.device);
    return 1;
}
```

and the command I am using at terminal is;

```
chetan@chetan-VirtualBox:~/hexinject-1.0/hexinject$ ./hexinject -s -i eth0

Unable to open the adapter. eth0 is not supported.
```

Now I tried lspci to check the controller and it shows;

```
chetan@chetan-VirtualBox:~/hexinject-1.0/hexinject$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:06.0 USB controller: Apple Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB
00:07.0 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:0d.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
```

and I tried ifconfig eth0 and it shows;

```
chetan@chetan-VirtualBox:~/hexinject-1.0/hexinject$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:34:d0:0f  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe34:d00f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13497 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11729 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10512163 (10.5 MB)  TX bytes:1754437 (1.7 MB)
```

that means there is no problem with eth0.
But then why it is not showing the output as it should.
I am using Ubuntu on VirtualBox on a Windows 8 host. Also the version of hexinject is 1.0 used here. Here is the sourceforge link, http://sourceforge.net/projects/hexinject/files/hexinject-1.0/.

I am new to network programming so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `pcap_open_live()` requires `errbuf` exactly for error description, but you missed printing it in your message. You would add its contents to your print for future starts.

Second, I'm 90% sure the reason is that you start your program as a usual user, without root privileges (I guess this due to `$` shell prompt suffix). By default, attaching to network interfaces is allowed only for root, or at least for user with `CAP_NET_ADMIN` and `CAP_NET_RAW` capabilities. You would retry the test under `su`, `sudo` or analog.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the mistake. Works just fine with root privileges. And I will add errbuf description. Thanks for that too.